# Is there a noticeable difference between defining & declaring the struct in one block vs. declaring then defining the struct?

Tags: c, struct, nodes, typedef

I want to know if these two are equivalent and if so, if one is more efficient:

```
typedef struct test test;

struct test {
    bigThing* thing;
    anotherThing* thingTwo;
    int var1;
    int var2;
};
```

and

```
typedef struct test {
    bigThing* thing;
    anotherThing* thingTwo;
    int var1;
    int var2;
} test ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a noticeable difference between defining & declaring the struct in one block vs. declaring then defining the struct?

No.

> I want to know if these two are equivalent

Yes.

> if so, if one is more efficient:

There is no difference in program execution. These all are abstract C language things, with no effect on program performance.

The first one is more efficient to type, two words less.

Comment: Thank you very much this answered my question very clearly

Answer (score 0):

both of them are equivalent due to the keyword `typedef` as in first example :

```
typedef struct test test;

struct test {
    bigThing* thing;
    anotherThing* thingTwo;
    int var1;
    int var2;
};
```

when you said `typedef struct test test;` this means aliasing the type `test` to `struct test` which means that wherever you write `test` , it's same as writing `struct test`.

but look in the second example you provided:

```
typedef struct test {
    bigThing* thing;
    anotherThing* thingTwo;
    int var1;
    int var2;
} test ;
```

due to the keyword `typedef` , meaning that wherever you write the type `test` , it's aliased to be

```
struct test {
    bigThing* thing;
    anotherThing* thingTwo;
    int var1;
    int var2;
}
```

which is the same but it's not convenient to write it like this , if you don't understand the above example , examine the following code :

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct test{
     int x;
     int y;
    }t1 ;

    t1.x = 10;
    t1.y = 2;

    printf("t1 = {%d, %d}", t1.x, t1.y);

    return 0;
}
```

and here is image of output :

[image]

so in the first code example you write , writing `test x;` is equivalent to :

```
struct test x;
```

while in the second code you provided , writing `test x;` is equivalent to :

```
struct test{
 int x;
 int y;
}x;
```

where both of them are equivalent but for me , it's more convenient to use the declaration of `struct` as in the first example you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Both your examples will compile to have the same effect. However, the duplication may lead to coders mixing, for instance:

```
test foobar1;
struct test foobar2;
```

There is an advantage to using your second example (slightly modified below.)

```
typedef struct {
    bigThing* thing;
    anotherThing* thingTwo;
    int var1;
    int var2;
} test_t;
```

This version omits the unnecessary token ahead of the curly brace. It also requires one fewer lines of code to be read and understood. Finally, this version uses a convention of "_t" to indicate that it is a (user defined) datatype.

The exception to one claim above is, for instance, declaring a struct to support a linked list. This will need a pointer to instances of itself. Under these requirements, a token must appear before the curly brace:

```
typedef struct node {
    int value;
    struct node *next; // "node_t" not encountered yet, so "struct node" required
} node_t;
```